# How to include additional data in one entity from other tables (via joins or subqueries) and still have it be insertable/updatable?

Tags: eclipselink

So I have the following code working correctly on my ecommerce site.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "v_customer_wishlist")
@NamedQuery(name = "VCustomerWishlist.findAll", query = "SELECT w FROM VCustomerWishlist w")
public class VCustomerWishlist implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "cart_id")
    private int _cartId;
    //get/set methods
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "_wishlist", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<VCustomerWishlistItem> _items;
    //get/set methods
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "v_customer_wishlist_items")
@NamedQuery(name = "VCustomerWishlistItem.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM VCustomerWishlistItem i")
public class VCustomerWishlistItem implements Serializable {
    ...
    public VCustomerWishlistItem(int cartId, int productId) {
        VCustomerWishlistItemPK id = new VCustomerWishlistItemPK (cartId, productId);
        setId(id);
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    private VCustomerWishlistItemPK id; //is PK for cartId and productId 
    //get/set methods
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id")
    private VCustomerWishlist _wishlist;
    //get/set methods
    ...
    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String _productName;
    //get/set methods
    ...
}
```

Then somewhere in my backing bean, I could do somethin like this (simplified version):

```
...
VCustomerWishlist wishlist = getCustomer().getWishlistById(cartId);
...
VCustomerWishlistItem item = new VCustomerWishlistItem(wishlist.getId(), product.getId());
...
item.setSequenceNum(wishlist.getItems().size()+1);
item.setProductName(product.getName());
item.setQuantity(1);
wishlist.addItem(item);
wishlistItemService.save(item);
...
```

So I can add items (product references) to wishlist and JPA will correctly generate the INSERT INTO queries and so forth.

However, upon thinking about it, I thought it would be better to retrieve this data directly from my 'master_products' table instead of what was stored in the VCustomerWishlistItem.

This way I would always have the most up-to-date productName, unitPrice and so forth for wishlist items saved weeks or months before.

The thing is, if I modify the view in my database to include this additional info by adding joins or subqueries; as soon as add joins or subqueries to my view, it becomes non-inserable/updatable.

I thought that it could be done via JPLQ in one @NamedQuery definition, but I understand these are designed to be used manually when retrieving desired sets. As opposed to the nice built-in way that JPA automatically retrieves the wishlist.items resolving it with the indicating annotation properties.

The fantasy property would be one where I can specify a direct table source for the entity, ignoring the join and subquery tables.

So for example, if the source for 'v_customer_wishlist_items_readonly' was:

```
SELECT 
    `cwi`.`cart_id` AS `cart_id`,
    `cwi`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
    `cwi`.`sequence_num` AS `sequence_num`,
    `mp_readonly`.`product_name` AS `product_name`,
    `mp_readonly`.`product_web_id` AS `product_web_id`,
    `mp_readonly`.`unit_price` AS `unit_price`,
    `cwi`.`quantity` AS `quantity`,
    `mp_readonly`.`unit_price`*`csci`.`quantity` AS `item_subtotal`,
    `cwi`.`create_datetime` AS `create_datetime`,
    `cwi`.`update_datetime` AS `update_datetime`
FROM
    `customer_wishlist_items` `cwi` JOIN `master_products` `mp_readonly` ON `cwi`.`product_id` = `mp_readonly`.`product_id`
ORDER BY `cwi`.`sequence_num`;
```

It would be ideal to have a an annotation where I could indicate that primary table name is 'customer_wishlist_items', so all updates/inserts would only apply to this table and changes to the rest of the read-only fields would be ignored.

So somethint like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "v_customer_wishlist_items_readonly")
@PrimaryTable(name = "customer_wishlist_items") //fantasy annotation
@NamedQuery(name = "VCustomerWishlistItem.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM VCustomerWishlistItem s")
public class VCustomerWishlistItem implements Serializable {
...
```

Does anyone know what would be the correct way of implementing this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: wheres the BalusC of eclipselink when you need one? upon further review, it looks like the SecondaryTable annotation would do what I want to do if I had a single PK in the wishlist items entity. as it stands, SecondaryTable wants to find both fields in PK in both 'master_products'. and 'customer_wishlist_items' tables. however, 'master' products has  product_id as PK and 'customer_wishlist_items' has both cart_id and product_id as PK, product_id being also FK to 'master_products'. I think I'm getting closer, it looks like I should be able to do it through this annotation or similar...

Comment: ok, upon further experimentation, it looks like I can eliminate the possibility of using SecondaryTable. the docs state that SecondaryTable is used when data from entity spreads across other tables. the thing is, it also wants to save data to those secondary tables. I'm using SecondaryTable just as lookup data to go along with my primary table. is there a way to tell eclipselink to not try to save secondary table data? if I was able to do this, then my requirements would be met.

Comment: Ok, so I was wrong, using SecondaryTable  was not the correct approach. I ended up using the KISS technique. I simply added a ManyToOne Product member variable to my VCustomerWishlistItem entity with @JoinColumn(name="product_id", insertable=false, updatable=false) and voila! everything is good now. I have access to my actual master_products from table from the wishlist item entity. Which is ultimately what I wanted.

Comment: Secondary tables are really just extensions of the primary table, and would mean a new product insert every time you added a VCustomerWishlistItem. With JPA's derived identifiers (2.0) allowing you to mark the relationships as IDs, do you really need/want the embedded id still?  Alternatively, you can mark your existing '_wishlist' relationship with MapsId in the current model and EclipseLink will set the values in your embeddedId for you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use derived ids or the MapsId to let JPA set your foreign key/id columns for you?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "v_customer_wishlist_items")
@NamedQuery(name = "VCustomerWishlistItem.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM VCustomerWishlistItem i")
public class VCustomerWishlistItem implements Serializable {
    ...
    public VCustomerWishlistItem(VCustomerWishlist cart, Product product) {
    this._wishList = cart;
    this._product = product;
    setId(new VCustomerWishlistItemPK());//JPA will populate this for you
}

    @EmbeddedId
    private VCustomerWishlistItemPK id; //is PK for cartId and productId 
    //get/set methods
    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("cartId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id")
    private VCustomerWishlist _wishlist;
    //get/set methods
    ...
    @MapsId("productId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product _product;
    //get/set methods
    ...
}
```

With this, you don't need to have or lookup the cartId/productId values at all as JPA will figure them out and set them for you, allowing you do just use code like:

```
VCustomerWishlistItem item = new VCustomerWishlistItem(wishlist, product);
...
item.setSequenceNum(wishlist.getItems().size()+1);
item.setQuantity(1);
wishlist.addItem(item);
wishlistItemService.save(item);
```

You should probably just set the sequenceNum and add the item to the wishlist in the item constructor, though I'm not a fan this approach to sequencing as it can lead to concurrency issues and problems maintaining it.

You can also do away with the EmbeddedId if you don't need it within your entity and use it as a primary key class; you'd just have to change the property names within it to match the relationships names from the entity:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(VCustomerWishlistItemPK.class)
@Table(name = "v_customer_wishlist_items")
@NamedQuery(name = "VCustomerWishlistItem.findAll", query = "SELECT i FROM VCustomerWishlistItem i")
public class VCustomerWishlistItem implements Serializable {
    ...
    public VCustomerWishlistItem(VCustomerWishlist cart, Product product) {
        this._wishList = cart;
        this._product = product;
    }

    ...
    @ManyToOne
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id")
    private VCustomerWishlist _wishlist;
    //get/set methods
    ...
    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product _product;
    //get/set methods
    ...
}
```

The primary key class might then look like:

```
public class VCustomerWishlistItemPK {
  public Integer _product;
  public Integer _wishlist;
  //optional getter/setter methods..
}
```

The properties within the ID class must match the names of the properties in your entities, but use the type of the primary key from the referenced class.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris, it looks like a cleaner way to do it. I'll try it out later this week and will post my results here.

Comment: Hi @Chris, I tried to use your second example. from what I understood, I added same member variables and get/set methods in PK class, but get this error. The derived composite primary key attribute [_wishlist] of type [com.ingeniotechnologies.apps.cultivartewebstore.entity.VCustomerWishlist] from [com.ingeniotechnologies.apps.cultivartewebstore.entity.VCustomerWishlistItemPK] should be of the same type as its parent id field from [com.ingeniotechnologies.apps.cultivartewebstore.entity.VCustomerWishlist]. That is, it should be of type [java.lang.Integer]. what do you think I'm missing?

Comment: The error indicates it expects an Integer _wishlist property within your VCustomerWishlistItemPK ID class; It could be an issue with auto boxing if you already have it set to be an 'int'. Integer should be fine if it works, but I don't remember trying with the basic java types for identity; I usually use the wrapper types to allow for nulls and eventual sequence generation.

Comment: Hi again @Chris, I modified my class according to your @IdClass example and added the member variables to PK class as suggested. I sill get following error: `There should be one non-read-only mapping defined for the primary key field [v_customer_wishlist_items.product_id].`. So I'm still stuck. What do you think I'm missing?

Comment: This is just for product_id? Only difference I see is that I missed (c&p error) putting a OneToOne or ManyToOne annotation on it, so it'd be interesting to see how your EclipseLink is processing the class and mapping when deploying (you can turn on logging to finest and it'll tell you as it finds each and every mapping). It might be ignoring the JoinColumn, or giving a warning/error that it is doing so because it is missing the mapping annotation, I'm not sure. Try adding it, but if it doesn't work, check the logs.

Comment: I really appreciate your help @Chris. I guess not fully understanding the spec doesn't help me. I'll give it a shot some other time once I have time to read up on the spec to better understand it. Thanks!